# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String LetterType(Byte)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have this code in MVC c#, which its concept is ok. the "x.Letter.Kind" is numbber which I want to translated to a text when I am creating the list. So I wrote a function (LetterType) ,which takes a Byte and returns its associated text. But when the program runs, it gives me an error which says:

> {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String LetterType(Byte)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

I cannnot understand what it means. can somebody help me on this issue?
Thank you

```
 public JsonResult GetLetterList(DataTablesParam param)
    {
        int fld_id = 23571;
        int userId = 1454;
        int totalCount = 0;
        List<ViewLetterInformation> list = new List<ViewLetterInformation>();
        using (WebECartableEntities db = new WebECartableEntities())
        {
            int pageNo = 1;
            if (param.iDisplayStart >= param.iDisplayLength)
            {
               pageNo = param.iDisplayStart / param.iDisplayLength + 1;
            }                    
            totalCount = db.Referrings.Where(x => x.usr_Receiver__Id == userId && x.fld_Id == fld_id).Count();
            list = db.Referrings.Where(x => x.usr_Receiver__Id == userId && x.fld_Id == fld_id).OrderBy(x => x.Letter_Id).Skip((pageNo - 1) * param.iDisplayLength).Take(param.iDisplayLength).Select(x => new ViewLetterInformation                        
            {
               Letter_Id = x.Letter_Id,
               ProjectCode = x.Letter.Project.Code,
               LetterType = LetterType(x.Letter.Kind)   //This line gives error
               Ref_subject = x.Subject
             }).ToList();
             return Json(new
                {
                    aaData = list,
                    sEcho = param.sEcho,
                    iTotalDisplayRecords = totalCount,
                    iTotalRecords = list.Count()
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }                
        }
    }


 private string LetterType(byte LetterType)
    {
        string result = "";
        switch (LetterType)
        {
            case 0:
            case 4:
            case 8:
                result = "Import";
                break;
            case 1:
            case 5:
            case 9:
                result = "Export";
                break;
            case 2:
            case 6:
            case 10:
                result = "Internal";
                break;
            default:
                result = "";
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

if I use

```
 LetterType = x.Letter.Kind.toString()
```

instead of

```
 LetterType = LetterType(x.Letter.Kind)
```

it works fine, but I need its equivalent text data.

Thank you

Comment: If you put an `AsEnumerable` before the `Select` that will cause your projection to occur in memory where you don't have to worry about translating your code to SQL.

Comment: You can get your `list` from, then apply `LetterType` filter. Linq to entities will not be able to convert your method into the SQL statement.

Comment: Is LetterType  an enumeration?  If so cast instead of using kind.  Try LetterType = (Put enumeration type here, not the actual enumeration name)LetterType

Comment: @jdweng: it is not

Comment: @juharr: it was not successful

Comment: @nnmmss As in you got the same error, or a new one, or did it just not return the desired results?

Comment: @juharr: Sorry , it worked. Thanks. what was the reason?

Comment: The issue is that EF is trying to convert your C# code to SQL.  It knows how to do that for most C# operators and common libraries, but it doesn't for your custom method.  So by using `AsEnumerable` you're telling to stop translating to SQL at that point and do the rest of the Linq code in memory after fetching the data.

Answer (score -1):

Try bringing the entity into memory by calling .ToList() like this:

```
list = db.Referrings.ToList().Where(...).Select(...).ToList();
```

Comment: Doing a `ToList` on the `DBSet` will pull back the entire table.  Instead it should be done after the `Where` so you only pull back the desired rows.  Further it's better to use `AsEnumerable` so you don't have to create an unneeded intermediate list and iterate the results twice.